# Jetpack Compose :Check count of Text max lines

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a scenario where I need to show a button if the Text max lines exceed 9, Otherwise the button shouldn't appear.

I tried to check in the developer android guide but couldnt find any solution.

Below is my code:

```
                    Text(
                        //text = item.content,
                        text = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. " +
                                "Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, " +
                                "when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. " +
                                "It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software " +
                                "like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",

                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(bottom = 4.dp),
                        fontSize = 16.sp,
                        //maxLines = 6,
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1,
                    )
```

Answer (score 6):

The following works for me:

```
Column {
    var textOverflow by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    Text(
        modifier = Modifier.size(50.dp),
        text = "1234567891",
        fontSize = 16.sp,
        maxLines = 2,
        onTextLayout = { textLayoutResult ->
            textOverflow = textLayoutResult.hasVisualOverflow
        },
        textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1,
    )
    if(textOverflow) {
        Button(onClick = {}) {
            Text("Hello")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How to show the above implementation in compose preview.